# Postorder traversal using onestack with prev variable

Tags: java, postorder

I am unable to understand this code using one stack method here in this code previous variable is used and i am unable to understand how it will give the result to post order traversal can anyone explain the intuition behind this code

```
class BinaryTree 
{ 
    Node root; 
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
     ArrayList<Integer> postOrderIterative(Node node) 
    { 
        Stack<Node> S = new Stack<Node>(); 
        if (node == null) 
            return list; 
        S.push(node); 
        Node prev = null; 
        while (!S.isEmpty()) 
        { 
            Node current = S.peek(); 
            if (prev == null || prev.left == current || 
                                        prev.right == current) 
            { 
                if (current.left != null) 
                    S.push(current.left); 
                else if (current.right != null) 
                    S.push(current.right); 
                else
                { 
                    S.pop(); 
                    list.add(current.data); 
                } 
            } 
            else if (current.left == prev) 
            { 
                if (current.right != null) 
                    S.push(current.right); 
                else
                { 
                    S.pop(); 
                    list.add(current.data); 
                } 
            } 
            else if (current.right == prev) 
            { 
                S.pop(); 
                list.add(current.data); 
            } 
 
            prev = current; 
        } 
 
        return list; 
}
```

Comment: Where did you get this code from?  That will help us understand it.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-postorder-traversal-using-stack/